# How to Layer Custom Form Control Elements on Parent

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a custom calendar/date picker form control in Nativescript/Angular. Using animation I change the opacity of the calendar element when the user clicks on the down/up arrow. Works perfectly on a test page all by itself but when I put it on a page with other controls, it pushes down all the other controls on the page. I have tried changing the z-index and the X/Y coordinates to position it off the page but all the page elements after the control are still offset by the calendar height.

Is there a solution for this problem? And will setting the z-index allow it to hover over the page elements when the calendar is in the open position?

Playground sample: play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=gdtDry&v=19

Comment: It depends on your layout and stylings, hard to say what is the issue with seeing any code.

Comment: can you add the code or create a working sample to help you further

Comment: Let me see if I create a sample in the playground.

Comment: I added a stripped version of control to the playground. It illustrates the problem of offsetting the controls beneath the custom control (although it's not the working control because I use different icon fonts, moment.js etc and I didn't add all them to the sample). It does use my layout and css:

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=gdtDry&v=19

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this question. I didn't add a code sample at the start because I thought someone might have encountered the offset issue before, and it's a lot of code spread out over three different components.

Comment: I tried on your calendar playground it is not working properly, it shows a date picker but [?] as in left and right and when I clicked on that got the following error  `ERROR: ERROR TypeError: _co.monthBack is not a function. (In '_co.monthBack()', '_co.monthBack' is undefined)`

Comment: I didn't add that code because the problem is with the layout and the calendar dialog taking up too much space, not the full functionality of the date picker.

Comment: You can understand the basics of Layering layouts in NativeScript by reading this article, https://shiv19.com/how-to-layer-items-in-nativescript/ and then you can use visibility binding to show/hide layers.

Comment: @ShivaPrasad. Thanks for your comment. Since this is a custom form control component (it gets added to a page like <calendarPicker></calendarPicker>) how would the parent form know than a collapsed element in the control has to be layered over other controls on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the visibility property to the layout element containing the calendar dialog removed the offset issue.

```
visibility="{{ open ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"
```

Still working on getting the calendar dialog to open on top of the other elements on the page.